# Java - What are the additional 8 bytes of output generated by AES/CCM/NoPadding?

Tags: aes, padding, ccm

What are the additional 8 bytes of output used for in Java's (Bouncycastle) `AES/CCM/NoPadding`? I do not believe this is padding as I am requesting "NoPadding," and the block size is not 128, 192, or 256 bit. Is this some sort of Message Integrity Check (MIC)?

For example:

- Encrypting 16 bytes yields 24 bytes of output.
- Encrypting 20 bytes yields 28 bytes of output.
- Encrypting 31 bytes yields 39 bytes of output.

BTW.: The reason I ask is that I am trying to send/receive encrypted data from a bluetooth node. The bluetooth's firmware, written in C, encrypts data with AES/CCM with the same first 16 bytes of output as I get here, but only produces a 4-byte MIC (total of 20 bytes). I'm working on finding a solution to this. Apparently Bouncy Castle isn't supported in C?

Answer (score 2):

The additional 8 bytes are the Message authentication code (MAC), which is called the Message integrity check (MIC) in Bluetooth terminology.

For more info, see [here](http://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.nrf52832.ps.v1.1%2Fccm.html).